# How to use virtualenvwrapper in Supervisor?

Tags: python, deployment, virtualenv, supervisord, virtualenvwrapper

When I was developing and testing my project, I used to use virtualenvwrapper to manage the environment and run it:

```
workon myproject
python myproject.py
```

Of course, once I was in the right virtualenv, I was using the right version of Python, and other corresponding libraries for running my project.

Now, I want to use Supervisord to manage the same project as it is ready for deployment. The question is what is the proper way to tell Supervisord to activate the right virtualenv before executing the script? Do I need to write a separate bash script that does this, and call that script in the command field of Supervisord config file?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

One way to use your virtualenv from the command line is to use the python executable located inside of your virtualenv.

for me i have my virtual envs in `.virtualenvs` directory.  For example

`/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/yourenv/bin/python`

no need to `workon`

for a `supervisor.conf` managing a tornado app i do:

```
command=/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/myapp/bin/python /usr/share/nginx/www/myapp/application.py --port=%(process_num)s
```

Comment: and does this also automatically deal with all the other libraries I pip installed inside that particular virtualenv correctly? Or I need to set those up separately with Supervisor separately?

Comment: related to above, do i need to fiddle with `environment` setting in the supervisor config?

Comment: @MLister - by using your virtualenv python this will automatically allow you to access all packages installed in that virtualenv, I have never needed to use `environment`.  I guess using it depends on whether you need to set environmentally variables for your process

Comment: I found sth wrong. When I do 'source .../activate ; python script.py', there is one process, but when I do '/path/to/env/python script.py', there are two. And in later condition, supervisor can not restart the program correctly.

Comment: What if you do stuff in `bin/postactivate` and `bin/postdeactivate`, like setting environment variables? Doesn't seem like this approach would handle that correctly.

Comment: He clearly said that you get packages and python that you won't get environmental variables. However that being said especially if there is only few of those you can set them manually. Does it going to work? command=MY_VAR=13 /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/myapp/bin/python /usr/share/nginx/www/myapp/application.py

Answer (score 12):

Add your virtualenv/bin path to your `supervisord.conf`'s `environment`:

```
[program:myproj-uwsgi]
process_name=myproj-uwsgi
command=/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myproj/bin/uwsgi
    --chdir /home/myuser/projects/myproj
    -w myproj:app
environment=PATH="/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myproj/bin:%(ENV_PATH)s"
user=myuser
group=myuser
killasgroup=true
startsecs=5
stopwaitsecs=10
```

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but it seems to be the most reasonable way to go. It allows people to run `click` based clis easily.

Answer (score 5):

First, run

```
$ workon myproject
$ dirname `which python`
/home/username/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin
```

Add the following

```
environment=PATH="/home/username/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin"
```

to the related supervisord.conf under [program:blabla] section.

Comment: This didn't work for me. supervisord still uses the regular PATH.

Comment: What is the version you're using?

Comment: I'm using supervisord 3.1.3

Comment: I had similar problem with above solution not working, until I realized that after changing config it's worth to restart supervisord. I do not say it's you problem, I do say future stackoverflow dwellers restart supervisord just in case. :-)