# how to get supervisord to see module in working directory using virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, supervisord

I have the following supervisord configuration and I'm having trouble getting the subprocess to see a module that is in the root of the working directory specified in the config. There is a /srv/www/company/utils.py file that the script needs to see.

```
[program:python_worker_2]
command=/opt/company/venv/bin/python scripts/supervisor/python_worker.py
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s
numprocs=4
numprocs_start=0
priority=999
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
startretries=3
exitcodes=0,2
stopsignal=TERM
stopwaitsecs=10
user=jobadmn
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/python_worker_2_stdout.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=50MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10
stdout_capture_maxbytes=0
stdout_events_enabled=false
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/python_worker_2_stderr.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=50MB
stderr_logfile_backups=10
stderr_capture_maxbytes=0
stderr_events_enabled=false
directory=/srv/www/company
serverurl=AUTO
```

I can run the script manually using the same commands specified in the supervisor config file, but I get the following when I try to run the job within supervisor:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/supervisor/python_worker.py", line 8, in <module>
    import utils
ImportError: No module named utils
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use virtualenvwrapper in Supervisor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202760/how-to-use-virtualenvwrapper-in-supervisor)

Answer (score 2):

The surest approach to behave the same way sourcing the `activate` script does is to... start a shell, and have it source the activate script.

```
command=bash -c 'source /opt/company/venv/bin/activate; exec python scripts/supervisor/python_worker.py'
```

Comment: This does work. Thank you. I'm wondering though if it's possible to have the virtualenv set up without adding a command prior to the execution of the script? Either that or some other way to make the executed python aware of the utils file that doesn't involve running a spare command? If not I can accept this, but I thought I would ask. Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.