# pycurl version conflict between installed packages

Tags: python, centos, centos7, pycurl

I have the following situation, I have a web server with Plesk installed in it, to update Plesk **yum** is required as the server is over **CentOS**. Now on the server I have installed an on demand image resizing solution ([Thumbor](https://github.com/thumbor/thumbor)) which depends on the pycurl package version greater than or equal to 7.19.0 and minor than 7.20.0, if I install the package required by **Thumbor** then **yum** brokes, and on excecution throws an error saying that the required version of pycurl is not installed, and the same happens to **Thumbor**. So is a situation where one of the two(Thumbor or yum) have to die :) . My question is, how can I have two versions of pycurl installed on my server in order to run both, Thumbor and yum? Or, is any way to have both living on the same server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a virtual environment. Install the web server's version of pycurl in the virtual environment. Run the web server in the virtual environment.

When you need to run yum do so outside of that virtual environment, so the web server's version of pycurl does not apply.

Depending upon which version of Python you're using for the web server one of these ought to get you started:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks. I have ran the virtual environment, but once I activate it how can I ensure that it will always be running. At the beginning I had thumbor running using supervisord, but now with the virtualenv how can I use the virtualenv without entering or activating it, and how can I keep the service running in the virtual environment running even if I close the console?.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202760/how-to-use-virtualenvwrapper-in-supervisor